# Discord.py создание тикета ошибка ctx

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я новичок в питоне, не могу понять, почему не проходит проверка на то, указан ли человек после команды и само задание.
Цель кода:
Человек пишет в определенном канале команду !задача @ИмяФамилия работа
Бот должен в определенной категории создать канал(это работает).
Но вот проверка на ввел ли человек ссылку на работника и текст задания нет.
Код:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['задача']) #
async def задание(stx,ctx,member: discord.Member = None,*,arg = None):
   CheckTaskChannel = stx.message.channel            # проверяем, можно ли работать команде в этом чате
   TaskChannel = bot.get_channel(951917790518988830) # канал, где данная команда будет работать.
   if member is None:
     await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = '**:grey_exclamation: Обязательно укажите: пользователя!**'))
   elif arg is None:
     await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = '**:grey_exclamation: Обязательно укажите: задание!**'))
   else:
     if CheckTaskChannel == TaskChannel: #Если сообщение написано в данном канале, выполняется код.
       await stx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
       author = stx.message.author
       guild = stx.message.guild
       creport = discord.utils.get(stx.guild.categories, name = 'Задания') #название категории, где будет создаваться тема.
       await guild.create_text_channel(f'Задание {author.name}', overwrites = None, category = creport, reason = 'Создание нового тикета.')
       server = bot.get_guild(703596629814673428) # ID сервера.
       for channel in server.channels:
           if channel.name == f'Задание {author.name}':
               break
     else: # Если команда !задача не в том канале, ничего не происходит.
       channel = bot.message.channel(951917790518988830)
       await stx.send('1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**

Ну для начала писать имя функции на русском - идея не очень. Лучше добавить `задание` в качестве имени команды в `@bot.command`:

```
@bot.command(name="задание", aliases=['задача'])
...
```

**2**

В команду первым аргументом всегда приходит `ctx` (`commands.Context`). У вас функция принимает `stx` и `ctx`. в данном случае ctx - не контекст, а обязательный аргумент к команде. Если человек вводит `!задача @упоминание задача_1 , то бот видит это так:

ctx - @упоминание

member - задача_1

arg - не указанно

Тогда если убрать stx, то всё будет работать:

```
@bot.command(name="задание", aliases=['задача'])
async def task(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member = None, *, arg=None):
    CheckTaskChannel = ctx.message.channel  # проверяем, можно ли работать команде в этом чате
    TaskChannel = bot.get_channel(951917790518988830)  # канал, где данная команда будет работать.
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description='**:grey_exclamation: Обязательно укажите: пользователя!**'))
    elif arg is None:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description='**:grey_exclamation: Обязательно укажите: задание!**'))
    else:
        if CheckTaskChannel == TaskChannel:  # Если сообщение написано в данном канале, выполняется код.
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
            author = ctx.message.author
            guild = ctx.message.guild
            creport = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name='Задания')  # название категории, где будет создаваться тема.
            await guild.create_text_channel(f'Задание {author.name}', overwrites=None, category=creport, reason='Создание нового тикета.')
            server = bot.get_guild(703596629814673428)  # ID сервера.
            for channel in server.channels:
                if channel.name == f'Задание {author.name}':
                    break
        else:  # Если команда !задача не в том канале, ничего не происходит.
            channel = bot.message.channel(951917790518988830)
            await ctx.send('1')
```